# Make time series stationary and find Arma model in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I'm new with R and time series.

I have the following data in a text-file:

> 2953
>   2635
>   2404
>   2413
>   2136
>   1565
>   1451
>   2037
>   2477
>   2785
>   2994
>   2681
>   3098
>   2708
>   2517
>   2445
>   2087
>   1801
>   1216
>   2173
>   2286
>   3121
>   3458
>   3511
>   3524
>   2767
>   2744
>   2603
>   2527
>   1846
>   1066
>   2327
>   3066
>   3048
>   3806
>   4042
>   3583
>   3438
>   2957
>   2885
>   2744
>   1837
>   1447
>   2504
>   3248
>   3098
>   4318
>   3561
>   3316
>   3379
>   2717
>   2354
>   2445
>   1542
>   1606
>   2590
>   3588
>   3202
>   4704
>   4005
>   3810
>   3488
>   2781
>   2944
>   2817
>   1960
>   1937
>   2903
>   3357
>   3552
>   4581
>   3905
>   4581
>   4037
>   3345
>   3175
>   2808
>   2050
>   1719
>   3143
>   3756
>   4776
>   4540
>   4309
>   4563
>   3506
>   3665
>   3361
>   3094
>   2440
>   1633
>   2935
>   4159
>   4159
>   4894
>   4921
>   4577
>   4155
>   3851
>   3429
>   3370
>   2726
>   1674
>   3257
>   4731
>   4481
>   5443
>   5566
>   5044
>   4781
>   4014
>   3561
>   3801
>   2685
>   1805
>   3756
>   4227
>   4595
>   5702
>   4681
>   4395
>   4459
>   4191
>   3742
>   3279
>   2468
>   1742
>   3366
>   3633
>   3701
>   4926
>   4522
>   5275
>   4717
>   4114
>   3851
>   3493
>   2654
>   2168
>   3561
>   4305
>   4413
>   5307
>   5361
>   4948
>   4472
>   3846
>   3715
>   3343
>   2939
>   1615
>   3497
>   3915
>   4858
>   4962
>   4504
>   4767
>   4291
>   4091
>   4164
>   3915
>   3130
>   1696
>   3887
>   4749
>   4781
>   5089
>   5484
>   5072
>   4611
>   4117
>   3910
>   4252
>   3624
>   1678
>   3851
>   5021
>   4581
>   6195
>   5338
>   4909
>   4640
>   3706
>   4113
>   3879
>   3411
>   2043
>   3736
>   4490
>   3715
>   5623
>   4671
>   5591
>   5461
>   4795
>   4846
>   4843
>   3278
>   2411
>   4278
>   4639
>   4559
>   6404
>   4851
>   6480
>   6394
>   5752
>   4718
>   4659
>   3842
>   2873
>   5556
>   5389
>   6135
>   6707
>   5220
>   6249
>   5281
>   4192
>   4867
>   3752
>   3492
>   1979
>   4584
>   5139
>   5044
>   5501
>   5044
>   5035
>   5167
>   4650
>   5298
>   4373
>   3941
>   2334
>   4381
>   5665
>   4393
>   5232
>   5876
>   5900
>   5704
>   4718
>   4650
>   4446
>   3061
>   2155
>   4274
>   4695
>   4362
>   4889
>   5370
>   5072
>   4985
>   3978
>   4139
>   3995
>   3025
>   1949
>   4357
>   4638
>   3994
>   6174
>   5656
>   4411
>   5504
>   4463
>   4458
>   4528
>   2830
>   1843
>   5042
>   5348
>   5257
>   6699
>   5388
>   6001
>   5966
>   4845
>   4507
>   4214
>   3460
>   1833
>   4978
>   6464
>   5820
>   6447
>   6191
>   6628
>   5452
>   5295
>   5080
>   5564
>   3965
>   2062
>   5099
>   6162
>   5529
>   6416
>   6382
>   5624
>   5785
>   4644
>   5331
>   5143
>   4596
>   2180
>   5786
>   5840
>   5666
>   6360
>   6219
>   6082
>   5653
>   5726
>   5049
>   5859
>   4091
>   2167
>   6480
>   7375
>   6583
>   7251
>   6730
>   6428
>   5228
>   4716
>   6101
>   5753
>   4000
>   2691
>   5898
>   6526
>   5840
>   6650
>   5717
>   7236
>   6523
>   5729
>   6004
>   5950
>   4690
>   3687
>   7791
>   7153
>   6434
>   7850
>   6809
>   8379
>   6914
>   6919
>   7265
>   6994
>   5503
>   3782
>   7502
>   8119
>   7292
>   6886
>   7049
>   7977
>   8519
>   6680
>   7994
>   7047
>   5782
>   3771
>   7906
>   8970
>   6077
>   7919
>   7340
>   7791
>   7368
>   8255
>   7816
>   7476
>   6696
>   4484
>   8274
>   8866
>   8572
>   9176
>   8645
>   8265
>   9558
>   7037
>   9101
>   8180
>   7072
>   3832
>   7253
>   8667
>   7658
>   8859
>   7291
>   7529
>   8715
>   8450
>   9085
>   8350
>   7080
>   3210
>   8221

I read this file with

```
chocs = read.table('chocs.txt',sep=",")
```

then I divide the data in train and test set:

```
train_set = ts(chocs[1:round(dim(chocs)[1]/100*80),], start = c(1957,7), frequency = 12)
test_set =  ts(chocs[-(1:round(dim(chocs)[1]/100*80)),], start = c(1984,6), frequency = 12)
```

This is the plot of the train set with the acf:

[plot of the train set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXeKd.jpg)

The train set is not stationary because there is a trend, a seasonal pattern and the variance increses with the time.
So how can I make this train set stationary and find the correct arima model? 
I need this arima model to make forecasts and test them with a test set.

Thanks for help!

Comment: I suggest installing the `forecast` package and reading [Forecasting: principles and practice](https://www.otexts.org/fpp), both by Rob Hyndman.  The online book addresses common tasks in forecasting and how to do them in R.

Comment: I used the forcast and timeSeries package. I used log and differencing to make it stationary. The ACF and PACF (for estimation the model) weren't really good, so my model looks not really similar to my stationary time series...